# PHP: if(function_exists('curl_init')) does that work?

Tags: php, curl

I have some code that that I only want to execute if `curl_init()` is present. I'm checking for it's existence with this code:

```
if(function_exists('curl_init'))
{
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.my-site.ext/' . $data . '/');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
}
```

The `if()` returns true, however the code inside throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-name/inc/myplugin_functions.php on line 15
```

How can I properly check whether `curl_init()` exists?

Comment: Yes that works, show more of your code to see where the error lies.

Comment: Most likely a typo in either of the two lines. But `extension_loaded()` is the alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [`is_callable()`](http://php.net/is_callable) like this:

```
if(is_callable('curl_init')){
  //Code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try `curl_exec` instead `curl_init`, perhaps help

```
if(function_exists('curl_exec'))
{
    // Code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, function_exists has worked for me in the past for the same cause.... are you sure that all curl related methods such as init setopt exec and close and the use of curl's resource handler are within the if block?? more of your code would be helpful for a better answer..

Answer (score 1):

It would work properly, its your code  you have inside the block that causes that problem.

All it does is returns TRUE if `curl_init` exists and is a function, FALSE otherwise.  This function would be available if cURL is available, regardless of what **curl_*** function you put in.